# Django pagination random: order_by('?')

Tags: django, random, pagination, django-queryset

I am loving Django, and liking its implemented pagination functionality. However, I encounter issues when attempting to split a randomly ordered queryset across multiple pages.

For example, I have 100 elements in a queryset, and wish to display them 25 at a time. Providing the context object as a queryset ordered randomly (with the .order_by('?') specification), a completely new queryset is loaded into the context each time a new page is requested (page 2, 3, 4).

Explicitly stated: how do I (or can I) request a single queryset, randomly ordered, and display it across digestible pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this really good answer will be useful to you: [How to have a "random" order on a set of objects with paging in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022535/how-to-have-a-random-order-on-a-set-of-objects-with-paging-in-django)

basically he suggests to cache the list of objects and refer to it with a session variable, so it can be maintained between the pages (using django pagination).

or you could manually randomize the list and pass a seed to maintain the randomification for the same user!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem recently where I didn't want to have to cache all the results.
What I did to resolve this was a combination of .extra() and raw().
This is what it looks like:

```
raw_sql = str(queryset.extra(select={'sort_key': 'random()'})
                          .order_by('sort_key').query)
set_seed = "SELECT setseed(%s);" % float(random_seed)
queryset = self.model.objects.raw(set_seed + raw_sql)
```

I believe this will only work for **postgres**. Doing a similar thing in MySQL is probably simpler since you can pass the seed directly to `RAND(123)`.
The seed can be stored in the session/a cookie/your frontend in the case of ajax calls.

**Warning - There is a better way**
This is actually a very slow operation. I found [this blog post](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/) describes a very good method both for retrieving a single result as well as sets of results.
In this case the seed will be used in your local random number generator.

Comment: I've managed to `cursor.execute("SELECT setseed(%s);" % seed)`, and thereafter right-on reading/constructing the queryset, and it works as well. Why? I needed a real queryset, with all the bells and whistles (in django-oscar...). objects.raw() delivers some kind of reduced list style result...anyway, this answer is the way to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achive this is to use some pagination APP like:

- [pure-pagination](https://github.com/jamespacileo/django-pure-pagination)
- [django-pagination](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination)
- [django-infinite-pagination](https://github.com/nigma/django-infinite-pagination)

Personally i use the first one, it integrates pretty well with Haystack.

```
 """ EXAMPLE: (django-pagination) """
     #paginate 10 results.

    {% autopaginate my_query 10 %}
```