# In django, creating a randomized object list with paging

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've been trying to get a list of model objects, randomize their order and paginate them in the template. I thought I've done it until I realize that in each next page call I had been re-randomizing objects rather than using the previously randomized list.

Is there anyway I can randomize the object list only while opening the page first time and after that use the same list without randomizing it while going to the next page?

Thanks.

Views.py

```
class index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_items = list(Electronics.objects.all())
        random.shuffle(all_items)

        paginator = Paginator(items, 24)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        items = paginator.get_page(page)    

        return render(request, 'home.html', {'items':items, 'header':'Homepage'})
```

home.html

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
{% for item in items %}
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-4'>
            <img src='{{ item.image.url|cut:"%22"|thumb}}'>
            <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
            <p>$ {{item.price}}</p>
            <form method='get'>
                <input value='Add to cart' type='submit' formaction= "{% url 'addtocart' item.id %}">
                <input value='View Details' type='submit' formaction= "{% url 'detail' item.id %}">
            </form> 
        <div><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>  

    <div class='pagination' align='center'>
        <span class='step-links'>
            {% if items.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page=1{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">&laquo; first</a>
                <a href="?page={{items.previous_page_number}}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
                Page {{items.number}} of {{items.paginator.num_pages}}
            </span>
            {% if items.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{items.next_page_number}}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">next</a>
                <a href="?page={{items.paginator.num_pages}}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">last &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check out this link, it will show you how to cache a queryset to pass from page to page (otherwise, each request will start over and you will be generating an overlapping paginated list): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022535/how-to-have-a-random-order-on-a-set-of-objects-with-paging-in-django

Comment: Also, dont use `list(Electronics.objects.all())`, since it causes the queryset to evaluate. A better way to randomize a queryset is `Electronics.objects.all().order_by('?')`

Comment: Thanks. But is there any other way? Since my dataset is going to be pretty big, I am not sure my PC can handle caching such a big dataset.

Comment: @Hybrid I think there would be somewhat 3-4 thousands of data. You think caching would work?

Comment: look at my answer below, it should help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this great snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10468/) to implement a randomized seeded queryset mixin. This will basically allow you to create a GET request to the view using the mixin (via a url such as `/electronics?page=1`), and then it will generate a `seed` which will be cached in your `session`, and then reused to pull iterative sets of records.

This shouldn't be too much of a burden on your load, since caching a `seed` is inexpensive - it is the use of `order_by('?')` which can be expensive, but 3-4 thousand records isn't considered that big for such a task.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I cant figure out how I should use this class. Should it be implemented as a view function?