# Duplicate data occurs when order_by ('?') and pagination is applied

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["get"])
    def home_list(self, request):
        data = extra_models.objects.order_by("?")
        print(data)
        paginator = self.paginator
        results = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(results, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

What I want to do is, I want the data of extra_models (objects) to come out randomly without duplication every time the home_list API is called.

However, I want to come out randomly but cut it out in 10 units. (settings.py pagination option applied)

The current problem is that the first 10 appear randomly, but when the next 10 appear, the first ones are also mixed.

In other words, data is being duplicated.

Duplicates do not occur within the same page.

If you move to the next page, data from the previous page is mixed.

Even if you try print(data) or print(serializer.data) in the middle, duplicate data is not delivered.

However, data duplication occurs from /home_list?page=2 when calling the actual API.

Which part should I check?

Comment: Well each request, the records are retrieved randomly. So it is perfectly possible that the 1-10 part the first time, contains items in the 11-20 part if the queryset is shuffeled. A web server is supposed to be *stateless*.

Comment: Willem // So how do I do what I want? I want to randomly shuffle the data I have, and then provide the shuffled data one after the other without duplicate.

Comment: you don't. Or you need some sort of way to "represent" the shuffling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a "random" order on a set of objects with paging in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022535/how-to-have-a-random-order-on-a-set-of-objects-with-paging-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect this behaviour when you're dealing with **`.order_by("?")`**.

Whenever a request hits in server's end, Django shuffles the objects and also ***Django doesn't preserve the previous `request` or `page`***

Comment: I thought I would preserve the data when applying the existing paging.. cause the data appeared without duplication. So how do I do what I want?

Comment: I would suggest to *shrink your feature* in such a way that show random **N** items, ***without pagination***. Thus youl will have N items randomly

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong here, The only reason why this is happening is because of *order_by("?")*. The API is stateless which means on the second API call when you call for Page=2 then it does not know which data is sent for page=1 and returns random data for page=2.
The only solution is to order your data by ASC or DESC